# Motion Animation in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, silverlight, animation, motion

This is probably a really dumb question, but I'm finding conflicting information. I have a project in WPF/VB.net 2010 that I want to create an alternate version of in Silverlight. However, it uses heavy amounts of animation, especially motion animation. Most of this animation takes advantage of storyboard double animations for either translate transforms or canvas left/top changes.

Can I convert this project over to Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Erno's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563088/erno) answer is basically correct, though you need to be aware that there are differences and debugging XAML can be a frustrating experience.

There is certainly a convergence between Silverlight and WPF that will only get stronger over time. I was at a talk by Mike Taulty where this came up and he said that the two would continue to coexist and functionality would migrate between the two.

Without seeing your XAML I can't say for sure, but Silverlight supports all the things you mention.

Comment: :) that is why I said 'test'. Silverlight gets to me every time because I started out with WPF (well... Avalon) and it keeps on getting better (closer to WPF) and fortunately WPF is learning from SL too (Visual State Manager)

Comment: @Erno - sorry, that sentence didn't come out as as I intended.

Comment: Uhm, did my reply made you think I took offence? I didn't. Should I?

Comment: just kidding. And I thought your answer was quite clear. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy it and test. Silverlight has Storyboards, double animations and canvases too.